# Mixing .wav files

Tags: c, wav

Hey I have problem with mixing 2 .wav files. In my project I know that they always have same specs also first file is always longer than the second one. My task is to mix two files with weighted average.
First file has always weight 1 and second file might have values from 0 to 1. My program is kinda working but the output has some noise. I thought that maybe the samples that I read are wrong, but if I put weight 1, which in my case means that file 2 completely overwrites file 1 result is perfect sound from file 1 and 2.

This is how my code looks
I should say that for number of samples from file 2 I do weighted average and after that the rest of output is file1 thats why its important that file1 is always longer than 2.

````
wave* add_files(wave* data_1, wave* data_2,float wage,int time)
{
    float temp1;
    float temp2;
    float temp3;
    wave* data_3 = malloc(sizeof(wave));
    data_3->header = data_1->header;
    data_3->n_size = data_1->n_size;
    data_3->sample_size= data_1->sample_size;
    data_3->samples = malloc(data_1->n_size  *(sizeof(int32_t)));
    for (int i = 0; i < data_1->n_size; ++i)
    {

        if (i < data_2->n_size)
        {
            temp1 = data_1->samples[i]; // data_->samples is array of samples which are int32_t thats why i need to convert them to flat
            temp2 = data_2->samples[i];
            temp3 = (temp1 * (1 - wage) + temp2 * wage);
            data_3->samples[i] = (int32_t)temp3;
        }
        else
        {

            data_3->samples[i] = data_1->samples[i];
        }
    }



    return data_3;
} ```
````

Comment: Are your samples actually 32-bit?

Comment: You are using `float`. But it does not have 32-bit significance, so there will be distortion if the sample have more significance than 24 bits. I suggest using `double`. The sample rates also need to be the same in both files.

Comment: You should also make sure that the result of the floating point calculation is in the correct range. For example if a calculation was supposed to be in 24 bit range but the inexactness of floating point put it just outside, for example `16777215.9` truncated to `16777215` is ok, but `16777216.0` is an out-of-range `16777216`.